# Shell script: Syntax error: ";;" unexpected (expecting "fi")

Tags: shell-script

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is failing so hoping someone here can shed some light on this:

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME=Container

if [ -d "/mnt/SSD/docker" ]; then
    if [ ! -d "/mnt/SSD/docker/$NAME/data" ]; then
        mkdir -p /mnt/SSD/docker/$NAME/data
    fi
    printf "\nPlease select installation method:\n\n"
    while true; do
        read -p "1. Re-create existing container
2. Create new container: " CHOICE
        case $CHOICE in
            1 )
            if [ "$(docker ps -a | grep $NAME)" ]; then
            IP=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $NAME)
            MAC=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.MacAddress}}{{end}}' $NAME)
            docker stop $NAME; docker rm $NAME; docker image rm repo/image
            break;;
            else
                printf "\nNo existing container found, going back to menu!\n\n";;
            fi
            2 )
            read -p 'Please enter the IP-address to use: ' IP
            read -p 'Please enter the MAC-address to use: ' MAC
            break;;
            * )
            printf "\nIncorrect or no selection made. Please enter 1 or 2.\n\n";;
        esac
    done
    docker run -d \
    -e JVM_HEAP=1024m -e TZ=Europe/Stockholm \
    --hostname=$NAME \
    --ip=$IP \
    --mac-address=$MAC \
    --name=$NAME --network=macvlan \
    --restart=always \
    -v /mnt/SSD/docker/$NAME/data:/$NAME/data \
    -v /mnt/HDD/Storage:/mnt/HDD/Storage \
    repo/image
else
    logger "ZFS pool SSD is not mounted; aborting $0!"
fi
```

binarysta's answer gets me past the syntax error but now that neither break nor exit are used in the case statement, the script simply doesn't do what it's supposed to anymore.

Choice 1. is supposed to run the commands after the case statement if the container exists (break;;) but go back to the menu (;;) or exit the script (exit;;) if it doesn't.

If I use break instead of ;; it will run the commands no matter what I select whereas ;; will go back to the menu and never run the commands after case.

Comment: Always try your code at https://shellcheck.net/ to pick up things like syntax errors

Comment: Next time you run into a scripting issue like this, please include the entire error message(s) including line numbers (or a description of what exactly is happening). Also, first try to reduce the script to a minimum needed to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

there are some syntax errors in `case` statement.

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME=Container

if [ -d "/mnt/SSD/docker" ]; then
    if [ ! -d "/mnt/SSD/docker/$NAME/data" ]; then
        mkdir -p /mnt/SSD/docker/$NAME/data
    fi
    printf "\nPlease select installation method:\n\n"
    while true; do
        read -p "1. Re-create existing container
2. Create new container: " CHOICE
        case $CHOICE in
            1 )
            if [ "$(docker ps -a | grep $NAME)" ]; then
            IP=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $NAME)
            MAC=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.MacAddress}}{{end}}' $NAME)
            docker stop $NAME; docker rm $NAME; docker image rm repo/image           
            else
                printf "\nNo existing container found, going back to menu!\n\n"
            fi
        ;;
            2 )
            read -p 'Please enter the IP-address to use: ' IP
            read -p 'Please enter the MAC-address to use: ' MAC
            ;;
            * )
            printf "\nIncorrect or no selection made. Please enter 1 or 2.\n\n"
        ;;
        esac
    done
    docker run -d \
    -e JVM_HEAP=1024m -e TZ=Europe/Stockholm \
    --hostname=$NAME \
    --ip=$IP \
    --mac-address=$MAC \
    --name=$NAME --network=macvlan \
    --restart=always \
    -v /mnt/SSD/docker/$NAME/data:/$NAME/data \
    -v /mnt/HDD/Storage:/mnt/HDD/Storage \
    repo/image
else
    logger "ZFS pool SSD is not mounted; aborting $0!"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

smonkey,
the ;; is for the seperation of the cases. They must be on that level and not inside the if. There it is a syntax error. So in the if you do only 'break' and the ;; at the end of the case (after the if)

hope that helps.

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME=Container

    while true; do
        read -p "1. Re-create existing container
2. Create new container: " CHOICE
        case $CHOICE in
            1 )
              echo 1 gekozen
        if [ "y" = "x" ] 
        then
          echo x
        else
          echo stop
          break
        fi
        ;;
            2 )
            echo 2 gekozen
            read -p 'Please enter the IP-address to use: ' IP
            read -p 'Please enter the MAC-address to use: ' MAC
        echo IP is $IP
        echo MAC is $MAC
        break;;
            * )
            printf "\nIncorrect or no selection made. Please enter 1 or 2.\n\n"
        ;;
        esac
    done
```